# Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle Folder font is black, how to fix it?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes, darkmode

I recently installed Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle. Everything looks great except the project column, the font also changed to black. It is very hard to read. Does anyone know how to change the setting and fixed it?
[image bleow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSHc3.png)

Comment: yes ..  use a different theme that is legible

Comment: Eclipse has its own Dark theme that doesn't require anything to be installed - did you try that?

Comment: actually, I also tried. No change. I still have the issue with the picture.

Comment: Are these Git projects by any chance? If yes, Git has color settings for project labels too and these settings would override theme provided colors. A quick check would be to check those colors Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Git, or try a new workspace and a new dummy project as a test. Let us know if that works - if not, can provide further instructions.

Comment: no, they are not git projects, I just practice some codes on my end. Now, I switch from the enterprise version to the Eclipse Jave version. Now it is working now.